# Redirect user with router depending on user type

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router

Our users are accessing the website from Windows PCs. We use HttpClient.get withCredentials = true to hit the API server, which uses Identity services to retrieve the username that the browser sent to the server.

I would like to route users based on if they are Admin they get redirected to the dashboard, otherwise to home route. Admin is when username == 'jdoe'.

How do I go about doing that?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashBoardComponent} from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

const APPROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(APPROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Several options but neither of them feel clean:

Create a dummy entry component that all users get redirected to, and in ngOnInit, have logic that navigates users to the correct components, but this doesn't feel like the correct thing to do.

Alternatively, I can always redirect to dashboard for all users and place a canActivate guard on it and redirect non-admin users to Home. But again this does not feel like the correct clean approach.